# Why is a percent sign appearing before each prompt on zsh in Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, zsh

I'm getting zsh set up in Windows and I'm getting a reverse (black on white (black terminal background)) percent symbol in the first character position in the line just above every prompt.

Usually that means there's no newline at the end of the file, for example when `cat`-ing a file.

It doesn't happen on my Mac or even on Mintty on Windows. But it does happen in ConEmu and the standard terminal app that CMD.EXE usually runs in.

I've already `unset` all my prompt strings as well as `precmd()` which I normally use to add a blank line above the prompt.

Any clue what it could be?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The relevant option probably is `PROMPT_SP`, explanaition from the manual

> Attempt  to  preserve  a  partial line (i.e. a line that did not end
>   with a newline) that would otherwise be
>                 covered up by the command prompt due to the PROMPT_CR option.  This works by outputting some  cursor-control
>                 characters, including a series of spaces, that should make the terminal wrap to the next line when a partial
>                 line is present (note that this is only successful if your terminal has automatic margins,  which  is  typical).
>
> When  a  partial line is preserved, by default you will see an inverse+bold character at the end of the partial line:  a `%` for a normal user or a `#` for root.  If set, the shell parameter `PROMPT_EOL_MARK`  can  be
>                 used to customize how the end of partial lines are shown.

So, either you do a

```
unsetopt PROMPT_SP
```

if you don't care about the covered up line (however in your case it seems to be a empty line, as you get the `%` sign at the beginning).

Or use

```
setopt PROMPT_CR
setopt PROMPT_SP
export PROMPT_EOL_MARK=""
```

which preserves partial lines, but removes the `%` -- at the cost of some empty lines over the prompt.

To make this permanent, update your `~/.zshrc`.

*This is a blind shot, as I cannot reproduce this behaviour in my `cmd.exe`.*

Comment: Thanks @mpy, this put me onto just the right spot to learn more. Here's what I came up with: 1) three things work, more if you combine options: unsetopt PROMPT_CR; unsetopt PROMPT_SP; and PROMPT_EOL_MARK="". 2) setting PROMPT_EOL_MARK="" gets rid of the annoying inverse+bold "%" character, but it still adds an additional line feed, so prompt looks different than on mintty or the Mac. 3) I ended up going with unsetopt PROMPT_SP as the best compromise. 4) using set and unset doesn't work unless you use the -o option. setopt and unsetopt work. If you'll fix I'll accept your answer :)

Comment: @scanny : I have to apologize for the `set`. Of course, it should've been `setopt` -- obviously I wrote my answer too fast. I updated my answer and tried to include also the point about the empty lines.

Comment: DO NOT `unsetopt PROMPT_SP`, see
https://github.com/vercel/hyper/issues/3586#issuecomment-732747948

Answer (score 2):

So I was having the exact same issue with my zsh + oh-my-zsh.

I have fixed it with the help from mpy and those lines :

setopt PROMPT_CR

setopt PROMPT_SP

export PROMPT_EOL_MARK=""

You just have to go to -> ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/XXXXXX
You need to open the theme that you are using on oh-my-zsh so for me for exemple its agnoster.

Just open this file and copy / past those 3 lines at the end of the file.

And its fixed !!

Hope you have a nice day and that this will help some people out.

PEACE

Comment: Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](https://superuser.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Super User way of saying thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can run mintty inside of ConEmu.  That got rid of the percents for me.

Here's what I have for task parameters:

```
/icon "%ConEmuDrive%\msys64\msys2.ico"
```

and commands:

```
set CHERE_INVOKING=1 & %ConEmuDrive%\\msys64\usr\bin\mintty.exe -i "%ConEmuDrive%\msys64\msys2.ico" -
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using zsh shell , run the below lines in the terminal:
echo 'setopt PROMPT_CR' >.zshrc
echo 'setopt PROMPT_SP' >.zshrc
echo 'export PROMPT_EOL_MARK=""' >.zshrc